# Binding to Element's Visibility value

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a checkable DropDownButton and a Grid.

I want to bind Button's IsChecked parameter with grid's Visibility value.

If (Visibility == Visible) IsCheked = true

I've tried to do like that:

```
IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=UsersDockWindow, Path=IsVisible}"
```

but it didn't work, cause IsVisible is readOnly property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a VisibilityToBooleanConverter and use that in your binding:

```
public class VisibilityToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, ...)
  {
    return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
  }
}
```

In your XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <!-- assuming the local: xmlns is mapped to the appropriate namespace -->
  <local:VisibilityToBooleanConverter x:Key="vbc" />
</Window.Resources>

IsChecked="{Binding Visibility,
                    ElementName=UsersDockWindow,
                    Converter={StaticResource vbc}}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx). Here's an example of [how to do the binding](http://andu-goes-west.blogspot.com/2009/05/wpf-boolean-to-visibility-converter.html) using that converter.

Comment: IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=UsersDockWindow, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}"

Doesn't work... apparently I need somewhing opposite - VisibilityToBooleanConverter, but there is not such a thing

Comment: Why don't you put the binding on the `UsersDockWindow.Visibility` and make it one way to the source? If that doesn't work, you can quickly write your own converter, there are number of examples on the net how to do it.